# Mysql Date to timestamp SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have release date in database as:

```
release_date
2010-12-02 00:00:00
```

and i have to get 50 rows from the data order by release date desc. Can anyone tell me how can i implement this in mysql sql query, some thing like

```
SELECT data.content,item.value
FROM contents 
 AS data 
JOIN items 
 AS item 
WHERE data.id=item.content_id 
ORDER BY data.release_date
```

please help, any idea will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT**

I am not asking how to limit it, but my problem is this query makes my script to  run forever. Sorry for not clearing this before.

**EDIT 2**

```
contents
id | content | Comment | release_date

items
id | content_id | name | release_date
```

my both tables. Both have around 250000 rows

Comment: Have you tried your query? What is the problem with it?

Comment: MySQL is working with `date` perfectly. It should be OK to sort it with `ORDER BY data.release_date DESC` without converting it to UNIX Timestamp

Comment: yes i tried but this query made my script run forever. its execution doesnt stop. and i also dont see any data as output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `DESC` and `LIMIT` in your existing query as like below

```
SELECT data.content,item.value
FROM contents 
 AS data 
JOIN items 
 AS item 
WHERE data.id=item.content_id 
ORDER BY data.release_date DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Comment: @Astha: Do you have indexes created on columns, especially on `data.id` and `item.content_id`?

Comment: @Astha: edit does not have much info, You have to post definition of tables. You can look up for the indexes using the query `explain table_nane`

Answer (score 1):

same as you have but than:

```
ORDER BY data.release_date DESC LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: Could you include a raw database structure?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$sql = "select data.content, item.value 
FROM contents as data 
JOIN items as item ON data.id=item.content_id 
ORDER BY data.release_date DESC
LIMIT 50";
```

Note the `DESC` for ordering in descending order, remove this clause and it will set to order in ascending order

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are most of the way there already. You missed DESC and you should add a LIMIT clause:

```
ORDER BY data.release_date DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be something like:

```
select data.content,item.value
from contents as data
   join items as item ON data.id=item.content_id
ORDER BY data.release_date
```

It's better to use ON clausule to join tables.